# Customer address edit and add event in Magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-address

I am using below event and observer to trigger customer address add and edit.

code for events.xml

```
 <event name="customer_address_save_after">
    <observer name="customer_addres_after_save_viv_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerAddressSaveObserver" />
</event>
```

Here is the observer file code.

```
  class CustomerAddressSaveObserver implements ObserverInterface { 

/**
 * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $customerRepository;
protected $_logger;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $customerAddress = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerAddress();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($customerAddress->getData());die;
}
```

}

But the event is not firing for me. Am i using the correct code?

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: once the customer changes address or added new address, i need to call one api in that observer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look below code if you still faced issues.

etc/events.xml(make sure your file name)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_address_save_after">
        <observer name="srtpl_customer_address_save_after" instance="Vendor\Frontendsample\Observer\Model" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer/Model.php (make sure you defined the proper path in event.xml at instance tag)

```
namespace Vendor\Frontendsample\Observer;

class Model implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        //$customer = $customerAddress->getCustomer(); //if you want to get customer details
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info($customerAddress->getData());//here you will get address data
    }
}
```

let me know if you have any query

reference file vendor/magento/module-customer/ObserverAfterAddressSaveObserver.php

don't forget to run below command if your event is not working
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Code is tested in magento2.2.6

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: customer_address_save_after is triggering multiple times in Magento ver. 2.4.2-p2. Any idea on why this is happening?